# Excel VBA Start and Stop Underlining within a footer with a Variable

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I would like to have a footer in the Rightfooter that has a string of text with a variable in it, no issues there but what I am finding some difficulty on is the syntax to begin underlining and terminate underlining at a specific point in the footer string. Basically, I need the work "Page" then 2 spaces that are underlined, then my page number which is generated by a variable also underlined, then 5 more spaces underlined thereafter, finally I need 10 more spaces not underlined in order to orient the footer to the correct position in the report that I am duplicating. Here is the code that I am attempting.

```
DIM pg as integer, WS as worksheet

pg = 14

With WS.PageSetup
    .RightFooter = "&Time New Roman""&12" & "Page" "&U,  " & pg & "   " "&U           "
End With
```

For this the first "&U, is getting an "Expected End Statment error. There is gobs of code in this thing that have been QC'd and this is the last QC element that is hanging me up, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your quotes are wrong `"&""Times New Roman,Regular""&12Page &U  " & pg & "  &U          "`

Comment: thanks, I'm almost certain that this would have worked for the thrust of the question I did the famous post a question then keep working on the problem and stumbled onto a usable solution. The use of white characters in my answer below is something that I've seen other people struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

```
With WS.PageSetup
    .RightFooter = "&""Times New Roman""&12 Page" & "&U  A-" & pg & "    " & "&U" & "&KFFFFFF PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP"
End With
```

So I figured out the syntax and realized that trailing spaces would not reorient my text to the left so I had to switch to making some text white and using invisible characters to push the block that I wanted further left. This is what I came up with and its working for me, hope this can help some other soul in the future trying to align text within a footer.